# Common storage area in macOS with Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I come from light low level code on IBM mainframes. I am doing heavy high level code on a Mac. I did SwiftUI for iOS but did not like it. I am giving AppKit a try.

I have a question about the basic format of my application. If there is another way of thinking about things that aligns more with Swift, please tell me. For my application there is an area of common storage that is available to my application anywhere. Passing the address of this area to each initializer seems like a pain, so I don’t want to do it.

I have defined a class, Common, that has the stuff I want. There is a structure, Default, that has the default values I use. For example in Default I have the background color for my buttons so when I have to change them from blue to aqua I can do it in one spot and not hundreds and miss a few.

```
class Common {
  var name = "a name"
}
struct Default {
  static let common = Common()
  static let buttonColor = 1
}
```

My understanding, and it compiles and works, is that this will work:

```
Default.common.name = "new"
let i = Default.buttonColor
print (Default.common.name)
print (i)
```

It may work, but is this in the spirit of Swift?

While doing this I had the thought that I could make all the fields in common static and then I would not even need Default.common and I could just do Common.

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/

Answer (score 2):

Using a singleton or statics is not a good idea. Use a regular struct or class that has instance variables and methods and allows for multiple instances.

You might only need one "Common" now, but in a future update to your app you may realize you need more than one. That would require a refactor of your entire app to move away from using a singleton or statics. Better to avoid such a design from the start.

Even if you never move beyond needing one Common, using a singleton or statics makes it very difficult to write test cases or to use mock objects.

There are ways to avoid passing an instance of `Common` to every initializer. Look at how things work in App Kit.

You could associate a `Common` with each `NSWindow` that is opened. You can access the window from any `NSView` in the view hierarchy. Any `NSViewController` can get the window from its view.

Or you could walk up the `NSResponder` chain until you find a responder that provides the `Common` instance that's been assigned to it.

Either of these two approaches makes it easy to support one Common initially as well as support any number of Common with little rework in the future. Only the top level code will need to be changed a bit to know which Common to give to each window. The rest of the code base just knows it can access its relevant Common instance, not caring whether there's more than one being used throughout the app.

BTW - the pattern I describe would work for iOS and UIKit, macOS and AppKit, SwiftUI, or just about any platform. It's also language independent, not just applicable to Swift.

---

Another consideration for things like button color in AppKit is to look into `NSAppearance` and the `appearance` property. Look at the documentation for [Appearance Customization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/appearance_customization). This alone could eliminate a large portion of your `Common`.